# Javascript URL (input field to Google)

Tags: javascript, input, formatting

I have a form with many input fields, like:

```
<input type="text" name="some_title" id="some_title" />
```

I want to make URLs to Google near each of these fields, so once I enter any text into a field, I can instantly google for it. I use such a code for URL:

```
<a onClick="window.open('http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&q='+encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('some_title').value));">Google</a>
```

However, such URL does not work (I can't even click it). I believe it has something to do about URL formatting, would anyone provide me with a solution?

I found some similar questions in the database, but all the answers used functions and other complex stuff, while I want to keep the javascript as simple as possible. I don't need to do anything with URLs after submitting the form, I just want simple links to Google (so I don't think complex functions are needed).

Comment: if I understood right why don't you use <a href=""> ? where is the link exactly?

Comment: The link is in window.open function. If I use such code:

`<a onClick="window.open('http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&q=');">Google</a>` it works, so I'm 100% sure it's a problem with URL formatting.

Comment: Could you provide a live example of where this doesn't work (e.g. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net))?  Here's one that I made - seems to be working: http://jsfiddle.net/LUnHq/

Comment: Qantas 94 Heavy, thanks a lot for your feedback and example. Most likely it was a problem with browser cache or something because my code works now. Thanks again.